# Can text input acts as a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, input

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td align="right" nowrap="" style="padding-top:4px;"><span class="ff_fontname" style="padding-right:10px;">How did you find us?</span></td>
<td nowrap="" style="padding-top:4px;">
<input type="checkbox" class="custcheck" name="address_referrer" id="fbook" value="Facebook" onclick="referrerCheck(this);" />
<label for="fbook" class="custlabel"><span class="ff_fontname">Facebook</span></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="middle" nowrap="" style="padding-right:10px;"></td>
<td nowrap="" style="padding-top:12px;">
<input type="checkbox" class="custcheck" name="address_referrer" id="pinter" value="Pinterest" onclick="referrerCheck(this);" />
<label for="pinter" class="custlabel"><span class="ff_fontname">Pinterest</span></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="middle" nowrap="" style="padding-right:10px;"></td>
<td nowrap="" style="padding-top:12px;">
<input type="checkbox" class="custcheck" name="address_referrer" id="friend" value="Friend" onclick="referrerCheck(this);" />
<label for="friend" class="custlabel"><span class="ff_fontname">Friend</span></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="middle" nowrap="" style="padding-right:10px;"></td>
<td nowrap="" style="padding-top:12px;">
<input type="checkbox" class="custcheck" name="address_referrer" id="other" value="Other" onclick="referrerCheck(this);" />
<label for="other" class="custlabel"><span class="ff_fontname">Other</span></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right" valign="middle" nowrap="" style="padding-right:10px;"></td>
<td nowrap="" style="padding-top:12px;">
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="address_referrer" id="other" value="" placeholder="Other.."  />
<label for="other" class="custlabel"></label></td>         
</tr>
</table>
<script>

function referrerCheck(objId){
  var max = document.cartform.address_referrer.length;
  for (var idx = 0; idx < max; idx++) {
    if (eval("document.cartform.address_referrer[" + idx + "].checked") == true) {
    document.cartform.address_referrer[idx].checked = false;
    }
  }
 objId.checked = true;
}
</script>
```

Website has a "How did you find us?" section when filling out billing data. Right now there is some javascript that makes the radio buttons act as checkboxes. What ever area is checked adds the value to the database. So if the "Facebook" checkbox is checked then the value "Facebook" gets added to the data base.

I need the "Other" input type to be a "text" input field rather than a "checkbox" field, so the customer can specify where they found us. I am able to get a text input field working, but then then the checkboxes above don't work anymore.

I need the bottom "Other" checkbox to be a text input and have tried the code in the snippet, but it causes the checkboxes to not function anymore.

What am I doing wrong? Can the text field act as a checkbox so it doesn't screw up the javascript?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". I don't even know what a textbox acting like a checkbox would mean.

Comment: An `id` needs to be unique

Comment: By "doesn't work" I mean that when the input is "text" for "Other" then the checkboxes above don't send their values to the database if they are chosen instead. Only the "Other" text field gets added to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your input text for other, must have another name, or it would cause a conflict of values, you can't persist two different meaning information into the same place.

See how I did here:

```js
function referrerCheck(option) {
  console.log(option.value);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td align="right" nowrap="" style="padding-top:4px;"><span class="ff_fontname" style="padding-right:10px;">How did you find us?</span></td>
<td nowrap="" style="padding-top:4px;">
<input type="checkbox" class="custcheck" name="address_referrer" id="fbook" value="Facebook" onclick="referrerCheck(this);" />
<label for="fbook" class="custlabel"><span class="ff_fontname">Facebook</span></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="middle" nowrap="" style="padding-right:10px;"></td>
<td nowrap="" style="padding-top:12px;">
<input type="checkbox" class="custcheck" name="address_referrer" id="pinter" value="Pinterest" onclick="referrerCheck(this);" />
<label for="pinter" class="custlabel"><span class="ff_fontname">Pinterest</span></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="middle" nowrap="" style="padding-right:10px;"></td>
<td nowrap="" style="padding-top:12px;">
<input type="checkbox" class="custcheck" name="address_referrer" id="friend" value="Friend" onclick="referrerCheck(this);" />
<label for="friend" class="custlabel"><span class="ff_fontname">Friend</span></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="middle" nowrap="" style="padding-right:10px;"></td>
<td nowrap="" style="padding-top:12px;">
<input type="checkbox" class="custcheck" name="address_referrer" id="other" value="Other" onclick="referrerCheck(this);" />
<label for="other" class="custlabel"><span class="ff_fontname">Other</span></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right" valign="middle" nowrap="" style="padding-right:10px;"></td>
<td nowrap="" style="padding-top:12px;">
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="other_address_referrer" id="other" value="" placeholder="Other.."  />
<label for="other" class="custlabel"></label></td>         
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This method doesn't send the data from the text field to the database. Did I add the javascript incorrectly?
`function referrerCheck(objId){
  var max = document.cartform.address_referrer.length;
  for (var idx = 0; idx < max; idx++) {
    if (eval("document.cartform.address_referrer[" + idx + "].checked") == true) {
    document.cartform.address_referrer[idx].checked = false;
    }
  }
 objId.checked = true;
}
function referrerCheck(option) {
  console.log(option.value);
}`

Comment: @J.Feeble with my solution  you need to create another column in your database table, and pass that "other" value for it

Answer (score 0):

Modify code as:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custcheck" name="address_referrer" id="other" value="Other" onclick="referrerCheck(this); enableOtherTextbox(this);" /> 
<label for="other" class="custlabel"><span class="ff_fontname">Other</span></label>
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="address_referrer" id="other" value="" placeholder="Other.."  />




<script>
    function enableOtherTextbox(chkBox)
    {
        if(chkBox.checked == true){
            document.getElementById('other').disabled = false;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('other').disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This solution allows the text field to add the values to the database, but the other checkboxes don't add their values if chosen.

Comment: you are getting the checkbox values, you can save them, AND you can compare if its other, then you can save the value of the textbox.